# How to fix "Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture" in Android Studio

Tags: android-emulator

I was just using Android Studio without issue and then one of the times I ran the project I got a list of errors saying "Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture".

I have already looked up the issue and tried updating windows, updating android studio, updating drivers, un-ticking the "Enable instant run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy" box in the settings, going to windows settings and enabling the microphone to be used by apps and I can't find any solution.

```
10:02 PM    Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture

10:02 PM    Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID

10:02 PM    Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

10:02 PM    Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

10:02 PM    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

10:02 PM    Emulator: C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

10:02 PM    Emulator: dsound: At

10:02 PM    Emulator: tempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

10:02 PM    Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

10:02 PM    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

10:02 PM    Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

10:02 PM    Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

10:02 PM    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
```

The emulator just has a black screen and won't do anything else, I don't care if the emulator makes sound or not I just want to see the visuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by plugging my microphone back into my computer. Not sure why that causes the issue but once plugged back in, the errors disappeared. The black screen still appeared but I made another virtual device in AVD manager and used that which worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

Easy Fix....

i am running windows 10 but should be same for other versions.

Right click the audio icon at bottom right and click open sound settings then under the input section in the right window pane click manage sound devices and then enable stereo mix under input devices...

now the emulator will run without the audio error..

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting the same error while building the project, when I noticed that my system is not having the **In-Built Microphone** then I connected an **External Microphone** then it worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

A Quick fix is to wipe data (Tools>AVD Manager>Drop-down under actions>wipe data) from emulator each time the issue arises.